# $C^k$ extension of a function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n.$ Suppose $f$ is continuous on $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ then continuous extension does not exist in general. For example $f(x)=1/x$ and $\Omega=(0,1)$ does not admit continuous extension on $\mathbb{R}$.

On the other hand, if $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\Omega$ then there exists a uniformly continuous function $g \in C(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $f=g$ on $\Omega.$ In other words uniformly continuous function admits uniformly continuous extensions on $\mathbb{R}^n.$

Are there any analogous results for higher derivatives? i.e. Under what conditions on $\Omega$ and $f,$ we get an extension of $f$ which is $C^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (k-times continuously differentiable)? Do we need regularity assumption on boundary($\partial \Omega$) of $\Omega?$

Rigorous proof/references will be appreciated.

Comment: If the $k$th order derivatives are uniformly continuous you can extend the function.

Answer (score 3):

This is covered in Theorem 5' of "Singular Integrals and Differentiability Properties of Functions", E. M. Stein (1970), Chapter 6 and Theorem 6.3 in "Sobolev Spaces" by Robert Adams John Fournier (2003), Chapter 6.